# Bookmarks in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: bookmarks, visual-studio-2010

Is there a quick way (via keyboard's shortcut) to move between bookmarks in VS 2010 (C++ project)?

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl+K, Ctrl+N  - Move to next bookmark
Ctrl+K, Ctrl+P –  Move to previous bookmark